# No green light showing on a Raspberry Pi 3 after 3 months of running

Tags: raspbian

I have a Raspberry Pi 3. Until yesterday night it was working perfectly then before I slept I switched off both my monitor and my Raspberry Pi 3. Today when I woke up and turned them both on I notice that the monitor was not showing anything and my Raspberry Pi 3 was showing a red light but not the green light
as it showed before. I thought that it was a monitor problem so I tried another monitor with a different HDMI cable but still no booting started. My OS is NOOBS.

The problem is that since I have switched on the Raspberry Pi 3 I notice that no green light shows up along with the red light. Only one red light shows up. this means that I am getting power but the Raspberry Pi is not  booting. It has only been 3 months since I bought my Raspberry Pi and I don't want to take it to a repairing shop. Please tell me what should I do so that the green light comes back on my Raspberry Pi and everything turns back to normal as it was until yesterday and I can start working on my Raspberry Pi 3 again.

Comment: If you want anyone to read your question you need to put some effort in grammar and structure.

Comment: Hello and welcome! Please take the [tour](https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/tour) and visit the [helpcenter](https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/help) to see how things work here. Please follow Milliways' advice, edit the question including a meaningful title and refrain from adding unrelated chatter ("read the whole...") from the title. Thanks.

Comment: Was it shut down properly? I would try a new image on a new SD card to rule that out as an issue.

Comment: No green light is what will happen if you power up with no SD card inserted.  If it happens with a card in, most likely the card is not formatted properly or has become corrupted.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Raspberry Pi 3 - Blank Screen - Red Led and no Green Led](https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/questions/55750/raspberry-pi-3-blank-screen-red-led-and-no-green-led)

Answer (score 1):

Replace the SD card.

Always have a spare with a known working OS. They aren't expensive and it doesn't have to be large or with a fast read/write speed (class 4 or 6 is fine to test)

Comment: I was in a hurry. Actually my grammar is quite good. During the time when I was writing the question I was feeling very tense and so I wrote the whole story and some of my grammar went wrong.

Comment: If you don't mind checking where you comment! My answer did not bring your Grammar into question. There should be 'add a comment' just below the critique above. :-)